# ¿Cómo definir múltiples relaciones hacia la misma tabla usando EntityFramework CodeFirst y FluentApi?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tengo un detalle con la relación de 3 tablas:

Tengo un POCO llamado 'Domicilios' de forma simplificada, está en la siguiente forma:

```
public class Domicilio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public int? ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
    public int? EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

Y tres POCOs más llamados 'Cliente', 'Proveedor' y 'Empresa'

```
 public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Domicilio> Domicilios { get; set; }
}

public class Proveedor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Domicilio> Domicilios { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public Domicilio Domicilio { get; set; }
}
```

Proveedor y Cliente tienen muchos Domicilios, hasta ahí sin problemas. El detalle es con la relación uno a uno o uno a cero, entre Empresa y Domicilio.

Creo que la llave foránea debe ir en la tabla de domicilios apuntando al Id de la empresa mediante la propiedad EmpresaId. Pero no logro hacerlo funcionar y los registros simplemente se guardan sin relacionar en la base de datos.

Estoy usando FluentApi para la configuración de forma simplificada.
Este es el código:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .ToTable("clientes")
            .HasMany(c => c.Domicilios)
            .WithOptional(d => d.Cliente)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClienteId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Proveedor>()
            .ToTable("proveedores")
            .HasMany(p => p.Domicilios)
            .WithOptional(d => d.Proveedor)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProveedorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Empresa>()
            .ToTable("empresas")
            .HasOptional(e => e.Domicilio)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(d => d.Empresa);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Domicilio>()
            .ToTable("domicilios");
    }
```

¿Cual es el error?

¿Es posible con EntityFramework que una tabla se comporte con `HasMany` para ciertas entidades y con `HasOptional` o `HasRequired` para otras?

¿Cómo defino que la llave foránea de empresa es `EmpresaId` en la tabla Domicilios usando FluentApi?

Comment: Pregunta, por que una Empresa no puede tener varios Domicilios? ya sea como Sucursales, o diferentes locales como almacenes

Comment: @DanielLuyo En realidad era por simplificar el ejemplo y no distraer mucho. 

En el código completo, mi clase Empresa tiene una colección de Sucursales y la clase Sucursal tiene una colección de Almacenes. Cada Almacen y Sucursal tienen un solo Domicilio, lo cual me deja con el mismo problema de la relación uno a uno.

Comment: Hola @DavidZavaleta ¿Por que una relación polimórfica?, ¿Que te llevo a tomar esa desición?, ¿Que quieres obtener al usar ese tipo de relación?

Comment: Hola @DavidZavaleta en mi opinión es una mala desición este tipo de relación https://www.swapbytes.com/por-que-no-debes-usar-relaciones-polimorficas/

Comment: Hola @PedroÁvila en realidad fue mi ultima opción intentando implementar una relacion one-to-zero-or-one entre la tabla empresas y la tabla domicilios. Leyendo a fondo sobre relaciones polimórficas, creo que no es lo que necesito para resolver el tema. Gracias por el enlace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las relaciones de Entity framework que sean de polimofirmo se puede establecer como una herencia normal de clase:

```
public class Domicilio
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
public string Direccion { get; set; }
public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
public int? ProveedorId { get; set; }
public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }


}
    public class Empresa : Domicilio
    {

public string Nombre { get; set; }

    }
```

EDITADO:
Para las relaciones de herencia en EF  no es necerario declar la clase hija como un dbset en el DbContext ni haría falta declarar sus relaciones. Solo iría la padre que este caso sería Domicilio:

En el Dbcontext la incluiría así

```
public dbset<Domicilio> Domicilio {set;get;}
```

Si tiene realació con otra tabla sería así:

**uno a uno**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Domicilio>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Tabla1)
               .WithOptional(e => e.ObjectDomicilio)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.DomicilioId);
```

**uno a mucho**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Domicilio>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Tabla1)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ObjectDomicilio)//Esto es lo unico que cambia
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.DomicilioId)
```

En este caso no tendrias acceso directo a Empresa desde el Dbcontext pero si puedes acceder a sus datos como así:

```
using(var context=new Dbcontext)
{
(Empresa)context.Domicilio.where(x=>x.ClienteId==1).tolist();
}
```

En este caso te retornaría todos los domicilios que tienen relacion con el cliente 1 y son de tipo Empresa.

Comment: Interesante, no había pensando en esa solución. Pero eso haría que EntityFramework cree una tabla Empresas con el campo 'nombre' más todos los campos de Domicilio para persistir los datos ¿cierto?

Comment: @David Zavaleta No, solo se creará una tabla Empresa con los datos de ella es decir Nombre y un ID que seria elmismo que va existir en la Tabla Domicilio, y una tabla Domicilio con sus Datos, seria mas o menos asi Empresa{Id=1,Nombre="Pepe"} y Domicilio{Id=1,Direccion="LOSPESA", ClienteID=1, ProvedorId=1}, entiendes

Comment: Entiendo ¿pero entonces lo que sugieres genera una relación uno a uno? en ese caso el ID de empresa va a ser el mismo que el ID de domicilio. Es decir, si el ID de domicilios va en el numero 100, aunque la empresa sea la primera insertada ¿va a tener un id 100, para coincidir con el Id en la tabla domicilios?

Comment: Aprovechando tus conocimientos de EF. Quiero generar en la tabla Empresas un campo DomicilioId y que sea mi llave extranjera apuntando al domicilio. ¿Es correcta esta configuración? 

modelBuilder.Entity<Empresa>()
                .ToTable("empresas")
                .HasRequired(e => e.Domicilio)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.DomicilioId);

Comment: @David Zavaleta así debe funcionar para una relación de uno a uno..

Answer (score 0):

Como te comente, es una pesima idea trabajar con una relación polimórfica [¿Por qué no debes usar relaciones polimórficas?](https://www.swapbytes.com/por-que-no-debes-usar-relaciones-polimorficas/)

Las entidades de negocio es plasmar el mundo real, en un diseño de negocio, cada entidad tiene sus propios atributos.

[image: Modelo de negocio]

Las entidades de negocio proveen información a otras entidades que las consumen.

Comment: Si entiendo esa parte, creo que formulé mal mi pregunta. Mi desconocimiento de EntityFramework me llevó a pensar en una alternativa parecida a lo que hace ActiveRecord y en realidad no necesitaba eso. Solo necesitaba especificar una configuración adicional en FluentApi. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para definir este tipo de ralación en EF debes poner como llave primaria la llave foranea de la entidad que deseas. pongamos el ejemplo Empresa-Domicilio.

```
public class Empresa
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Nombre { get; set; }
}

public class Domicilio
{
  [Key]
  public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
  public string Direccion { get; set; }
  public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
  public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
  public int? ProveedorId { get; set; }
  public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }    
  public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

Se utiliza [Key] con el objetivo de ke EF reconozca EmpresaId como su llave principal ya que no cumple la convencion de nomenclatura ID o ClassNameId. De esta forma no es posible crear otro Domicilio con la misma Empresa ya ke su Id se repetiria.